# WPF ProgressBar - TargetParameterCountException

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I am making my first WPF application, where I use the Youtube .NET API to upload a video to Youtube using the ResumableUploader.

This ResumableUploader works asynchronously and provides an event AsyncOperationProgress to periodically report its progress percentage.

I want a ProgressBar that will display this progress percentage. Here is some of the code I have for that:

```
void BtnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // generate video

    uploader = new ResumableUploader();
    uploader.AsyncOperationCompleted += OnDone;
    uploader.AsyncOperationProgress += OnProgress;
    uploader.InsertAsync(authenticator, newVideo.YouTubeEntry, new UserState());
}

void OnProgress(object sender, AsyncOperationProgressEventArgs e) {
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((SendOrPostCallback)delegate {
        PgbUpload.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }, DispatcherPriority.Background, null);
}
```

Where PgbUpload is my progress bar and the other identifiers are not important for the purpose of this question.

When I run this, OnProgress will be hit a few times, and then I will get a TargetParameterCountException. I have tried several different syntax for invoking the method asynchronously, none of which worked. I am sure the problem is the delegate because if I comment it out, the code works fine (but the ProgressBar isn't updated of course).

Here is the Exception Detail (partially in French):

> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException
>   was unhandled   Message=Nombre de
>   paramètres incorrects.
>   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          à System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object
>   obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean
>   skipVisibilityChecks)
>          à System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[]
>   args)
>          à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Boolean
>   isSingleParameter)
>          à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate callback, Object
>   args, Boolean isSingleParameter,
>   Delegate catchHandler)
>          à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Boolean
>   isSingleParameter, Delegate
>   catchHandler)
>          à System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>          à System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
>   state)
>          à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object
>   userData)
>          à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object
>   userData)
>          à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>          à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>          à System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>          à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>          à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr
>   lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          à MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr
>   lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          à MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object
>   o)
>          à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Boolean
>   isSingleParameter)
>          à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate callback, Object
>   args, Boolean isSingleParameter,
>   Delegate catchHandler)
>          à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Boolean
>   isSingleParameter, Delegate
>   catchHandler)
>          à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate
>   method, Object args, Boolean
>   isSingleParameter)
>          à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
>          à MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr
>   lParam)
>          à MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG&
>   msg)
>          à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)
>          à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)
>          à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
>          à System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object
>   ignore)
>          à System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window
>   window)
>          à System.Windows.Application.Run(Window
>   window)
>          à System.Windows.Application.Run()
>          à WpfApplication3.App.Main() dans h:\razor\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\WpfApplication3\WpfApplication3\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:ligne
>   0
>          à System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, String[] args)
>          à System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          à Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object
>   state)
>          à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>          à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:

Thanks for any help.

---

### **Edit: I just found out that if I don't use the Dispatcher and just call set the value directly, it works fine! Is OnProgress called on main UI thread? How can that be?**

Comment: Can you provide the StackTrace of the TargetParameterCountException?

Answer (score 1):

The uploader (or any async component) can sync with the thread that created it.  There are probably a variety of ways to do this, but the one I've seen before goes like this:

```
public class ResumableUploader {
  private SynchronizationContext _syncContext;
  public event EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> OnProgressChanged;

  public ResumableUploader() {
    _syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current; //Think of this as the current thread
  }

  private ReportProgressChanged(int progress) {
     if(OnProgressChanged != null) {
         _syncContext.Send(s => { OnProgressChanged(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(progress)); }, null);  //s is any data you want to pass in, here it is unused
     }
  }
}
```

Or, slightly more flexible but also more complex for the user/client would be if the user/client supplied the SynchronizationContext at instance creation:

```
public ResumableUploader(SynchronizationContext syncContext)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I didn't know about that. Not "accepting" the answer though because I still don't get why my first method (using Dispatcher) was throwing that exception.